# react/redux action creator returns undefined when more than one payload

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

Hey i've been trying to figure this out for days. I want to have in the reducer, two pieces of information, an id and the json that gets received, however what I have tried so far doesn't seem to work, any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

this is the root index.js file which uses redux-multi:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import multi from 'redux-multi'

import reducers from './reducers';
import PhotosIndex from './components/photos_index';
import PhotosNew from './components/photos_new';
import PhotosShow from './components/photos_show';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise, multi)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/photos/new" component={PhotosNew} />
                    <Route path="/photos/:id" component={PhotosShow} />
                    <Route path="/" component={PhotosIndex} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
    , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

this is actions file (actions folder -> index.js)

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_PHOTOS = 'fetch_photos';
export const DELETE_PHOTO = 'delete_photo';

const ROOT_URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'

export function fetchPhotos(){
    const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/photos`);

    return {
        type: FETCH_PHOTOS,
        payload: request
    };
}

export function deletePhoto(id){

    const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/photos`);

    const alldata = [id, request];

    return {
        type: DELETE_PHOTO,
        //payload is undefined
        payload: alldata
    }

    //also tried 
    //return {
    //  type: DELETE_PHOTO,
    //  id: id, - id is as expected
    //  payload: request - payload is undefined
    //}

    //also tried 
    //return {
    //  type: DELETE_PHOTO,
    //  id: id, - id is as expected
    //  payload: 'random string or any object' - payload is as expected
    //}
}
```

this is the reducer:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { FETCH_PHOTOS } from '../actions';
import { DELETE_PHOTO } from '../actions';

export default function(state = {}, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_PHOTOS:
            const first20 = action.payload.data.slice(0, 20);
            console.log(first20);
            return _.mapKeys(first20, 'id');

        case DELETE_PHOTO:


            //need to get two payloads into here, list of json elements and the id


            //const first20_new = action.payload[1].data.slice(0, 20);
            console.log(action.payload[1](data));
            //console.log('first20 ' + first20_new);
            console.log('data is: ' + action.payload[0]);
            console.log('delete photo' + action.payload[1]);

            // console.log('id is: ' + action.payload.data);

            const findItemFromData = action.payload[1].indexOf(action.payload[0]);
            console.log(findItemFromData);
            // const removeItemFromData = action.payload.request.splice(findItemFromData, 1);
            // return _.mapKeys(removeItemFromData, action.payload[0]);
        default:
            return state; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios functions return a **promise**, not a synchronous value. Check out the usage examples [here](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#example). Basically, to get access to the response you need to write

```js
axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/photos`)
  .then(response => {
    // do something with the response in here
  });
```

The problem with your action creators as-written is that they're synchronously creating the action object, whereas you don't have the data you need to create the action yet. You have to wait until the API response has returned before creating the action and dispatching it. You'll need to use something like `redux-thunk`, `redux-api-middleware`, or `redux-saga` to handle these types of asynchronously-created actions (or roll your own flavor).

If you use `redux-thunk` for example, your action creator will return a function, which is passed the function `dispatch`, which it can use to dispatch the action inside the success callback of your API call.

```js
function fetchPhotos() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // perform API call
    axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/photos`)
      .then(response => {
        // now that you have the response, you can dispatch the action
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_PHOTOS,
          payload: response
        });
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: ah I think I get what you're saying, so in that scenario, in the dispatch, I can have two actions like below?

type: FETCH_PHOTOS,
payload:response,
id: id

Comment: thanks for explaining that to me, I just tried my scenario and results are as expected. thanks again!

Comment: You should keep both the `id` and the `response` inside the payload as separate properties, but I'm not sure I understand the question. And you're welcome!